# Use Python to Create Image and Row of Boxes in Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to create a JPG that consists of an image stacked on top of a row of boxes. Below is a picture of what I'm trying to accomplish. Each of these boxes is an individual color.

**How do I add an image above the color palette (row of colors)?**

Here is the code I have tried:

```
palette, scores = ['#272727', '#fafafa', '#1a1a1a', '#979797', '#a1473d'], [0.75, 0.16, 0.05, 0.04, 0.0]

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(5,1))
ax = fig.add_subplot()
ax.axes.xaxis.set_visible(False)
ax.axes.yaxis.set_visible(False)

for i, color in enumerate(palette):
    x = i/len(palette)
    rect = Rectangle((x, 0), .20, 1, facecolor=color)
    ax.add_patch(rect)

plt.savefig(os.path.join(save_dir, f'{id+1}.png'))
```

Here is the outcome of my code:
[image]

Here is what I want:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `plt.GridSpec` (see doc [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.gridspec.GridSpec.html)).

See code below:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


palette, scores = ['#272727', '#fafafa', '#1a1a1a', '#979797', '#a1473d'], [0.75, 0.16, 0.05, 0.04, 0.0]

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6,10))
gs=plt.GridSpec(8,3)
ax=plt.subplot(gs[7:8,0:3])

ax.axes.xaxis.set_visible(False)
ax.axes.yaxis.set_visible(False)

for i, color in enumerate(palette):
    x = i/len(palette)
    rect = plt.Rectangle((x, 0), .20, 1, facecolor=color)
    ax.add_patch(rect)

plt.box(False)

ax2=plt.subplot(gs[0:7,0:3])
img=plt.imread('b.jpg')
ax2.imshow(img,aspect='auto')
ax2.axes.xaxis.set_visible(False)
ax2.axes.yaxis.set_visible(False)

plt.box(False)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

And the output returns the following:

[image]